# Comparing Maximum Likelihood Estimation vs Method of Moments

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand the differences between Maximum Likelihood Estimation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) and Method of Moments Estimation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics).

Suppose we have some data points $x_1, x_2....x_n$. We believe that these data points come from some Probability Distribution Function $f(x;\theta = \theta_1, \theta_2.., \theta_k)$. In this situation, $\theta$ is a vector of parameters corresponding to the Probability Distribution - e.g. in a Normal Distribution, $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2) = (\mu, \sigma^2)$

Suppose the goal of our problem is to estimate the components of $\theta$ using some estimation method e.g. Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE), Method of Moments (MM) . As I understand, here are the general properties of both estimation methods:

- Both MLE and MM are generally said to be "Consistent" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator) - this means that when the number of data points increases, the "sample" value of the estimator converges to the "true" value of the estimator.
- Both MLE and MM are generally said to be "Asymptotically Normal" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_distribution) - this means that as the number of data points increases, the distribution of the $\theta$ vector will follow a (Multivariate) Normal Distribution
- Both MLE and MM are NOT always Unbiased Estimators (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) - this means that at times, the Expected Value of the estimator will not always equal to the corresponding parameter within the probability distribution
- However, the MLE estimator is generally said to be an "Efficient" estimator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics), i.e. having the minimum variance property - whereas the MM estimator is not "Efficient". This means that if you take a probability distribution function and estimate the parameters of this distribution using MLE : the variance of the parameters from MLE will be the lowest possible variance when compared to any other method of estimation

**This brings me to my question:** If I have understood this correctly, MM and MLE both have the same advantages - but MLE has an additional advantage when compared to MM (i.e. minimum variance property). **Thus, are their truly any advantages to use MM over MLE to estimate $\theta$ for a probability distribution $f(x;\theta = \theta_1, \theta_2.., \theta_k)$**?

To begin to answer my own question, the first thing that comes to mind is that sometimes, MM might be computationally easier to when compared to MLE. The first example of this is the Gamma Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). If we were to use MLE for the Gamma Distribution, this would involve taking a derivative of a Gamma Function - and this is quite difficult. However, the MM estimator completely avoids this problem and actually has closed form solutions in this situation.

The other idea I have thought of that might be true is the concept of Robustness and Misspecification. For example, suppose I believe that $x_1, x_2....x_n$ come from distribution $f(x;\theta = \theta_1, \theta_2.., \theta_k)$ when in reality, they actually come from some other distribution $g(x;\theta = \theta_1, \theta_2.., \theta_k)$.

Thus, is it possible that somehow, in some situations , i.e. for specific choices of $f(x;\theta = \theta_1, \theta_2.., \theta_k)$ and  $g(x;\theta = \theta_1, \theta_2.., \theta_k)$ - **is it possible that MM might be a more suitable choice to estimate $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2.., \theta_k)$ when you are unsure of the underlying probability distribution function?** If so, what are examples of such situations (i.e. how can we characterize such situations) and to what extent can we quantify this suitability? **In general, are there some well-known advantages of MM compared to MLE?**

Thanks!